# How to save posts to transient?

Tags: wordpress, transient

My code:

```
if (!empty($packs = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pack', true))):
    if ( false === ( $q = get_transient( 'packs_list' ) ) ) {
        $params = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => '7',

            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'package_pack',
                    'value' => $packs,
                    'compare' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query($params);

        echo '<div class="products list_">';
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
                $q = include(rh_locate_template('inc/parts/main.php'));
            endwhile;  

        echo '</div>';

        set_transient( 'packs_list', $q, 1 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ); 
        wp_reset_postdata();    

    }
endif;
```

I am trying to save the entire generated list of posts to transient as html but doens't work. How can I save html output from this loop to transient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure what's in your include, the first issue you're having is that you can't echo output to your string which you want to save as a transient. You have to concatenate `$q` into a long string with all of the included HTML output.

Also, you probably want to use output buffering to get the contents of your included file template.

```
if (!empty($packs = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pack', true))):
    if ( false === ( $q = get_transient( 'packs_list' ) ) ) {
        $params = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => '7',

            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'package_pack',
                    'value' => $packs,
                    'compare' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );

        $wp_query = new WP_Query($params);

        $q = '<div class="products list_">';
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
                ob_start();
                include(rh_locate_template('inc/parts/main.php'));
                $q .= ob_get_clean();
            endwhile;  

        $q .= '</div>';

        set_transient( 'packs_list', $q, 1 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ); 
        wp_reset_postdata();    

    }
endif;
```

If you still need to output `$q` to the screen in this process, you can just

```
echo $q;
```

Where you need to.